# Finding the average of differences between each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning, everyone. I'm trying to try to find the differences between two rows. I'm trying to put a formula together, but I feel like I'm making things too complicated when an easier answer may be available, and my code's not perfect. Here's my example dataset.

```
cols = ['Name', 'Math', 'Science', 'English', "History"]
data = [['Tom', 100, 93, 95, 92], ['Nick', 89, 75, 82, 57], ['Julie', 99, 89, 76, 88], ['Sarah', 79, 78, 94, 88]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df
```

The output is this: [image]

My current (and non-working) formula is:

```
students = ['Tom', 'Nick', 'Julie', 'Sarah']
differences = []

def student_diff(student):
    for col in df.columns[1:]:
        for classmate in students:
            differences.append(abs(student[col] - classmate[col]))
            print (student, differences.mean())
              
student_diff('Tom')
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

All in all, I was hoping the output would be something like (for example with Tom):

```
Nick 19.25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# student to find difference
student = 'Tom'
# create your mask where the name is the student name 
mask = df['Name'].eq(student)
# concat you masks together and set the index
data = pd.concat([df[mask], df[~mask]]).set_index('Name')
# get the mean from the differnce
abs(data.iloc[0, :] - data.iloc[1:, :]).mean(axis=1)

Name
Nick     19.25
Julie     7.00
Sarah    10.25
dtype: float64
```

or if you did want a function

```
def student_diff(df: pd.DataFrame, student: str) -> pd.Series:
    # create your mask where the name is the student name 
    mask = df['Name'].eq(student)
    # concat you masks together and set the index
    data = pd.concat([df[mask], df[~mask]]).set_index('Name')
    # get the mean from the differnce
    return abs(data.iloc[0, :] - data.iloc[1:, :]).mean(axis=1)


student_diff(df=df, student='Nick')

Name
Tom      19.25
Julie    15.25
Sarah    14.00
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I like your solution.  I'm curious about one thing in particular.  What, if any, is the difference in behavior between using `data.iloc[0]` and `data.iloc[0, :]`?  I don't see any, but I am also a relative beginner to NumPy and Pandas.  Cheers!

Comment: @PhilipWrage there is no difference since we are not slicing columns. Same thing with `data.iloc[1:]` and `data.iloc[1:, :]` I just include the second `:` sometimes if I know I will want/need to go back and slice the columns later on. So if you were curious about the difference of everything except Math you can just add `return abs(data.iloc[0, 1:] - data.iloc[1:, 1:]).mean(axis=1)`

Comment: that makes perfect sense.  You are using the first index to identify the row (or row slice) you want, and the second index identifies the column (or column slice) you are interested in.  By specifying the `:` slice as the second index, you are saying you want every column - which would be default behavior - but you are leaving a placeholder for adjusting this in future calculations.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @PhilipWrage yes, you nailed it. You can find some additional information about indexing and selecting data with pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)